# How to paginate the get_users function?

Tags: functions, pagination, users

Im using the get_users function to show a custom list of users on the site. The only issue Im having a problem figuring out now is how to paginate the result.

This is a sample of the function that Im using:

[image: Sample Code Screen shot]

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of creating a pagination for the this function. I would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 9):

First get the total number of users:

```
$total_users = count_users();
//var_dump($total_users); //for debugging purpose
$total_users = $total_users['total_users'];
```

and the current page:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
```

Set a variable that will decide how many users to display per page:

```
$number = 20; // ie. 20 users page page
```

Then, in your $args array add the offset if the current page != 0, and the max number of users to return:

```
'offset' => $paged ? ($paged - 1) * $number : 0,
'number' => $number,
```

Now add your code from above, and create the page links:

```
// display the user list here

if($total_users > $number){

  $pl_args = array(
     'base'     => add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
     'format'   => '',
     'total'    => ceil($total_users / $number),
     'current'  => max(1, $paged),
  );

  // for ".../page/n"
  if($GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks())
    $pl_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(get_pagenum_link(1)).'page/%#%/', 'paged');

  echo paginate_links($pl_args);
}
```

See [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for a full list of arguments....

Comment: This was awesome and pointed me in the right direction, but it removes the second page of results how it was originally set up. Mainly `$pl_args['total']` should be "ceil" not "floor" since it is the total pages. And then 'offset' for the get_user $args should be `'offset' => $paged ? ($paged-1) * $number : 0,`. You need to remove 1 from $paged to get 0,1,2,3 instead of 0,2,3,4.

Comment: Thank you very much for the working and awesome snippet. Am using it in custom wordpress page backend created by add_menu_page and when navigating to the next page it says "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.". How i can solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Thank you @onetrickpony. Your code works